# Olympics data request

Tags: data-request

I am looking for Olympics data.

What I must have is all the world records in every competition (at least for modern Olympics) including: when and by who the world record was broken.

I would also like to have:

1. All athletes participating in every Olympiad including meta data such as birthdate, age, nationality, height, weight, etc.
2. For each competition the results of all the athletes in every round including final rankings.

Basically, I am looking for all possible data. I am sure it is stored somewhere, but can't find it.

Any clue where can I find this data?

Thanks

Comment: also see here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=olympics

Answer (score 2):

There is a [dataset of athlete details on kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results) that shows most of what you ask for at point 1 above (age, nationality, height, weight – although not birthdate) as well as the events that they participated in and what medals they got (if any). The data was scraped from [sports-reference.com](https://www.sports-reference.com) and is shown on Kaggle as being CC0 licensed (probably on the basis that under US copyright law you can't copyright a fact)<sup>1</sup>.

The Olympics section of sports-reference.com has [since closed](https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics.html) and instead redirects you to [olympedia.org](http://www.olympedia.org/), which doesn't seem to have a data download page. You may want to look through that site to see if there is anything more there.

---

<sup>1</sup> Depending on the circumstances in which you want to use the data, it might be relevant for you to know that this scraping *might* have been a breach of the [sports-reference.com policy on data use](https://www.sports-reference.com/data_use.html).